# Tests fail due to presence of long literal in output

Tags: list, python-2.7, pytest, assert

A few of my tests have an expected response and an actual response.
The actual is a response from the DB and it's comparing against a manually built list.

The code can be simplified to below:

```py
# List of tuples expected
expected = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]

# List of tuples actual. This is a response from the DB. I cannot control the 
# presence of L in the result
actual = repr([(long(1), long(2), long(3)),(long(4),long(5),long(6)),(long(7),long(8),long(9))])

# print(actual): [(1L,2L,3L),(4L,5L,6L),(7L,8L,9L)]
print(actual)

assert expected == actual
```

I would expect expected to equal actual in this case because the tuples are the same except for the L literal. However, it's not.

```
-  (1, 2, 3),
+  (1L, 2L, 3L),
?    +   +   +
```

My question is: how do I fix this without putting a `long(<entry>)` cast for every single expected entry?

I've tried using the json module to json.loads the result from the DB, but json.loads fails due to it not matching valid JSON. It complains due to missing commas.

I've tried using eval(actual), but it results in the same thing.

I've lastly tried using a for loop to iterate through the entries (in a vain attempt to use eval(loop_entry), but it results in splitting the list as if it was a string.

I know using `long(value)` in each entry in my expected works, but it's cumbersome when there are many lines with many entries on each line.

Comment: The problem is that your result is actually a string (due to `repr`), and to compare it to numbers you have to parse the numbers there. Something like `tuple([int(x[:-1]) for x in actual[1:-1].split(", ")])` will give you a tuple of numbers by just plainly stripping the "L" character from the numbers. Not nice, but should work...